# How to get multiple values of associative Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem to getting multiple values from an associative array. I try to find the solution but most of them showing that how to get single value of key from the array.

```
var data = []
0 : 5 , 6 
1 : 2 , 4 
2 : 3 , 9
```

Now I have to get value "5" and "6" from `index[0]`. How can I get it and separate them as variable?

Comment: Can you give us the actual object/array? What do you mean separate them as a variable? Are you trying to figure out how to reference the indexes?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have associative arrays, just arrays and/or objects

Comment: Are you asking for `var foo = index[0][0];` and `var bar = index[0][1];` ?

Comment: you can suppose it as data[0] = 5 ,6

Comment: `5,6` Is it an array or a string

Comment: `data[0] = 5 ,6` is valid JavaScript,  but it doesn't assign multiple values to the first index. It's equivalent to `data[0] = 5` .

Comment: they are in string format but seperate. Actually i am  getting this value from database and i have to use it in javascript

Comment: data: [Array]
   2: 37,13 (Str)
   1: 8,43 (Str)
   0: 9,33 (Str)      .This is i am getting from database

Comment: *"they are in string format but seperate."* So you have an array of arrays of strings? Can't you provide a valid JavaScript representation if your data instead of coming up with pseudocode? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: @shoaib Just copy-paste the format as it is

Comment: thats 0 is key and 5,6 its values. I am too confuse from it

Comment: actually i just decided to ask it from the person who code for it.. He said he make an array { "1 ,2 ,3" , "4,5,6" , "7,8,9" }. In this way i am getting value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you stored your data.

If each value is a string, then you would have to do something like;

```
var data = ['5,6', '2,4', '3,9'];
var splitted = data[0].split(',');
var fiveStr = splitted[0]; // value will be a string
var sixStr = splitted[1]; // value will be a string
```

If the value is another array (better) then:

```
var data = [[5,6],[2,4],[3,9]];
var five = data[0][0]; // value will be a number
var six = data[0][1]; // value will be a number
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have multidimensional array like following then you can use this example-

```
    var data = []
    data[0] = new Array(5,6);
    data[1] = new Array(2,4);
    data[2] = new Array(3,9);


for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
    {
        alert(data[i][j]);
    }

}
```

To check example use this link- http://jsfiddle.net/rfu93Lv6/